# How to add frame to an image in iOS and save to library

Tags: iphone, image-processing, frame

I want to build an app that user can add a frame (a png file with transparent) to another image(maybe from library) to make a new image and save it to library or upload to Facebook.
So, my question is how to make an image and its frame become unique image. Thanks for your helps!

Comment: What have you tried? Write down ideas about what would be your first go! and then we will tell you what you should do to perfect your pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it's helpful for you. I think you wants merge image and crop also May be It's helpful for you. It's work fine for me

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(190, 190);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

[imageViewTatoo.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(x1,y1,x2,y2) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDarken alpha:0.4];

UIImage *fullScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


imageView.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(fullScreenshot, nil, nil, nil);

imageView.image= fullScreenshot;
```

Comment: @QuangPhạmCông you are welcome. Accept (tick) the answer if it's working for you. may be it also helps other's :)